# Extract word after a known pattern in UNIX

Tags: regex, unix, grep, pattern-matching

I have a file called in.txt which contains a whole bunch of code, however I need to extract a user ID which is guaranteed to be of the form 'EID:nmb685', potentially with content before and/or after the guaranteed format. I want to extract the 'nmb685' using a bash script. I've tried some combinations of grep and sed but nothing has worked.

Comment: I see "unix" tag, pls report your grep version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your grep doesn't support `-p` but supports `-o`, you can combine grep and awk.

```
grep -o 'EID:\w\+' file|awk -F':' '{print $2}'
```

Though can it be done by awk alone, but this is more straightforward.

Comment: Kent, you are a savior. That works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If your grep supports `-P`, perl-regexp parameter, you may use this.

```
grep -oP 'EID:\K\w+' file
```

Answer (score 0):

What is being output after the ID? Is there anything consistent that you can match against?

If you know the length of the userid you can use:

```
grep "EID:......" in.txt > out.txt
```

or if you don't maybe something like this (checks all char/num followed by space, preceeded by EID:)

```
grep "EID:[A-Za-z0-9]* " in.txt > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but this works:

```
grep "EID:" in.txt | sed 's/\(.*\EID:......\).*/\1/g' | sed 's/^.*EID://'
```

1. Select all lines with the substring "EID:"
2. Remove everything after "EID:" plus 6 characters
3. Remove everything before (and including) "EID:"

Comment: this may have problem if one line containing multiple patterns like `EID:foo EID:bar`. but OP didn't mention that, so it might be ok as well.